# Pass multi parameters to ViewModel Primary Constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

I used [this link](https://proandroiddev.com/view-model-creation-in-android-android-architecture-components-kotlin-ce9f6b93a46b) for pass parameter to ViewModel constructor when pass one parameter no problem

```
class ViewModelFactory<T>(val creator: () -> T) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return creator() as T
   }
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.getViewModel(noinline creator: (() -> T)? = null): T {
return if (creator == null)
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(T::class.java)
else
    ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelFactory(creator)).get(T::class.java)
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> FragmentActivity.getViewModel(noinline creator: (() -> T)? = null): 
T {
return if (creator == null)
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(T::class.java)
else
    ViewModelProviders.of(this, ViewModelFactory(creator)).get(T::class.java)
}
```

but i do not know how to can pass multi parameters to Constructor and return it with above code.
can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getViewModel` function get lambda, that produces ViewModel, as parameter. And in this case, you could do something like this:

```
val param1 = ...
val param2 = ...
val param3 = ...
getViewModel {
   YourViewModel(param1, param2, param3...)
}
```

Lambda passed to `getViewModel` capture all params. And later you invoke this lambda at `ViewModelFactory` and create ViewModel:

```
override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
    return creator() as T
}
```